# Finding the function solution of the ODE $xy'=2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $$xy'=2y$$

Through separation of the variables I get $$\frac{1}{2y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dx$$
Integrating both sides I get $$\frac{1}{2}\ln y=\ln x$$
which leads to $$\ln y=2\ln x$$
Hence I get $$y=2x$$

But the solutions say the answer is $$y=cx^2$$
Have I made a mistake or are the solutions wrong?

Comment: when you go from $ln y = 2ln x$ to $y = 2x$ you are making a mistake. it should be $\ln y = \ln x^2$ and then to $y = x^2.$

Comment: By the way, you should be able to tell that $y = 2x$ isn't a solution by substituting back into the original equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget the constant of integration. $\ln(y) = 2\ln(x) + c$.

The step from 
$$
\ln(y) = 2\ln(x)
$$
to
$$
y = 2x
$$
is incorrect. You need to exponentiate both sides, that is
$$
e^{\ln(y)} = e^{2\ln(x) + c}
$$

Since $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses of each other, the result follows.

Comment: Why does $e^2ln(x)$ become $e^{x^2}$?

Comment: Because of the property of indices: $(a^p)^q = a^{pq} = (a^q)^p$. So $e^{2\ln(x)} = (e^{\ln(x)})^2$.

Comment: But that would give $e^2x$ but the solutions want $e^{x^2}$

Comment: No, $e^{2\ln(x)} = (e^{\ln(x)})^2 = x^2$, since $e^{\ln(x)} = x$. Note that the result is *not* $e^y = e^{x^2}$. Exponentiation undoes the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y'}{2y}=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)=\ln(x)+c$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(y)=\ln(Cx)$$
$$\ln(y)=2\ln(Cx)$$
$$\ln(y)=ln(Cx)^2$$
Now you can take the exponential for both sides 
$$y=kx^2$$